# Unbounded element infinity symbol shows as rectangle in XMLSpy

Tags: fonts, screenshot, xmlspy

I need to have screenshots of my XSD, and XMLSpy has great-looking and descriptive graphical view of XSD Schema. However, below unbounded elements, it tries to show a little infinity symbol in Arial and fails miserably, displaying small rectangle instead.

I've tried changing the font as XMLSpy FAQ suggests, and I've tried using Arial MS with no luck. I suspect that this might have something to do with my default system language, which is Croatian (Eastern European charset).

I've tried this both on Windows XP and Windows 7.

I could leave small rectangles (which looks unprofessional), I could Photoshop it (but there's a lot of it), but I'd really like to fix this somehow - it's one of those small things that frustrate immensely.

P.S. I hope this is viewed as programming related, since Super User is not out of beta yet.

P.P.S. On new clean XP installation with same Windows settings it works. Maybe Office screws with Arial when installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem and I reported it to Altova. Below is their response:

"Upon checking our issues tracking database I have found that this is a problem which we are already aware of. Consequently I have added your report to the existing bug entry in order to bolster its chances of an early resolution. It currently has the tracking number and title:

"26725 - Infinity symbol replaced by generic box character in Slavic locales"

..and will appear in the release notes here:

http://www.altova.com/Fixed_Defects.html

..when it is addressed.

In the meantime the only workaround - which is probably not practicable - is to change the locale in your region settings to "English" for example."

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Unicode display problems can be fixed by installing East Asian support. See Microsoft’s page on [Enabling International Support in Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/user/xpintlsupp.mspx). You could also try an alternative editor, if only for the images, like StylusStudio or Eclipse.